# Escape ';' in Terraform GitLab environment variables

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I have in terraform this resource:

```
resource "gitlab_group_variable" "gitlab-variable-connection-string" {
  group         = "1234567"
  key           = "QUEUE_CON_STR"
  value         = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.report.default_secondary_connection_string
  protected     = false
  masked        = true
  variable_type = "env_var"
}
```

But when I do an `terraform apply`, I receive this error:

```
Error: PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/1234567/variables/QUEUE_CON_STR: 400 {message: {value: [is invalid]}}

  on service-bus.tf line 61, in resource "gitlab_group_variable" "gitlab-variable-connection-string":
  61: resource "gitlab_group_variable" "gitlab-variable-connection-string" {
```

The message is invalid because have `;` , like this one:

```
Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=4k8a+a*************************************=
```

If I remove the `;` the `terraform apply` works well, and write the variable value.

How can I solve this in this line?

```
  value         = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.report.default_secondary_connection_string
```

I already tried `format("%s", azurerm_s...)` and `tostring(azurerm_s...)`, but didn't work.

Thanks

EDIT:
If I do next command, variable `TEST` is created with value `aaa` instead of `aaa;bbb=`

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: *********" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/1234567/variables" --form "key=TEST" --form "value=Endpoint=sb://*****.servicebus.windows.net/SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKeySharedAccessKey=aaa;bbb="
```

Comment: This may be a bug with either the API and/or the provider.

Comment: What happens if you wrap it with [`urlencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/urlencode.html) is the resulting variable still usable?